# Building docker image FROM scratch using a buildroot linux

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, buildroot

Okay, so this is a complicated topic, so a thanks to anyone who actually takes the time to read this. This all started by trying to create an executable from a python script to run on target arch.

The target arch is arm64. I am doing all of this on a MAC. The major gotcha is that the target device uses uclibc. if it used glibc or musl I would be able to cross compile using the ubuntu container described below or an alpine container with python. (using pyinstaller to create executable)

I created a buildx container and ran an ubuntu container on arm64 architecture (confirmed). From there I am using a tool called Buildroot from within the ubunutu container to create a custom linux filesystem. which after much waiting creates "rootfs.tar"

Okay now with all that non docker stuff out of the way. I copy this rootfs.tar file to my host and try to build an image to run my custom linux.

Docker file

```
FROM scratch
MAINTAINER peskyadmin
ADD rootfs.tar /
```

build command

```
docker buildx build -t "${DOCKER_USER}/testrtfs:latest" --platform linux/arm64 --push .
```

run command

```
docker run --privileged --entrypoint "/bin/sh" -it "$DOCKER_USER/testrtfs:latest" --platform linux/arm64
```

run output

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

Using the latest version of Docker Desktop. I don't think that the warning is an issue because when I run the ubunutu container created with buildx it shows the same error message, but is running on target arch

My question is what am I doing wrong? I do not understand this error. my gut is telling me the issue has to do with the dockerfile but I am not sure as it could be an issue when using buildroot to create the rootfs.tar?

The target cpu is a cortex A53 which is the same that is in the raspberry pi 3. I suppose that I could try to install the image directly onto the bare metal pi and then try to cross compile on there. But I really would like to keep everything virtualized on my mac.

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: @DanielCampos I updated my question to be more direct.

Comment: Q: Wouldn't it be much easier/more efficient/more robust to simply ensure that your target has Python installed?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any containers. Buildroot (and other build systems) do *cross* compiling, which means you can build for a different target than the machine you build on.

In other words, you simply select arm64 as the target architecture, make the build, then install the resulting rootfs on your target.

However, this rootfs completely replaces the target rootfs, so it's not relevant that the target is uclibc. So my guess is that you want to install just a single executable. Doing that is made more difficult with shared libraries, because you need to copy not just the executable, but also any libraries it links with. So it may help to configure Buildroot to link statically (`BR2_STATIC_LIBS`).

-EDIT-

If you want to run an environment similar to the target, it's not possible to run this in docker unless your build machine is also an arm64. That's what the warning "requested image's platform (linux/arm64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64)" is saying. Instead of docker, you need to use virtualisation, e.g. qemu.

You can bring up a qemu environment for arm64 with `make qemu_aarch64_virt_defconfig`. Check out board/qemu/aarch64-virt/readme.txt for how to start qemu.

Comment: Im not trying to compile rootfs for target system. I am trying to build a "Like system" that has a matching uclibc, and also a python and gcc.this is because when I run pyinstaller i create an executable for the target based on the current system. I cant do this process on the target because it cant have python installed. but i cant seem to get all 3

Comment: Q: Exactly why can't it have Python installed?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you've created a rootfs targeting arm64 (all libs and everything are targeted to arm) and you're running it in a container which is sharing its host kernel which is amd64.

So your container you have built should run on your target fine, but not your current host.

But I suspect this isn't what you wanted.

I suspect what you wanted was a container for application development on the target but hosted in a container.

if this isn't what you wanted disregard the next bit.

### Using a buildroot generated SDK in your container

in your buildroot .config set

`BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_ENVIRONMENT_SETUP=Y`

then make an sdk tarball from your buildroot project build directory (hopefully youre using OOTB) using buildroot

`make sdk`

this will produce a sdk tarball for you in the format of `*_sdk-buildroot.tar.gz`

Create a regular linux based dockerfile (pick your favourite) instead of starting from scratch and copying in the arm rootfs, and in your Dockerfile untar and relocate the sdk into some area of your choosing

```
ADD --chown="${USERNAME}":"${GROUP}" /*_sdk-buildroot.tar.gz ${YOUR_SDK}
RUN mv ${YOUR_SDK}/*_sdk-buildroot/ ${YOUR_SDK}/sdk/
WORKDIR ${YOUR_SDK}/sdk
RUN ./relocate-sdk.sh
```

when you want to do your sdk based builds you can simply souce in the new script which the `BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_ENVIRONMENT_SETUP=Y` flag creates

```
source ${YOUR_SDK}/sdk/environment-setup
```

and all you compile flags and pkgs, etc. are all now set so when you configure your build it will be targeting your platform and all your tools are in this new container.